# A set $S$ is constructed as follows. To begin, $S = \{0,10\}$. Repeatedly, as long as possible, if $x$ is an...

Tags: polynomials

A set $S$ is constructed as follows. To begin, $S = \{0,10\}$. Repeatedly, as long as possible, if $x$ is an integer root of some nonzero polynomial $a_{n}x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_{1}x + a_0$ for some $n\geq{1}$, all of whose coefficients $a_i$ are elements of $S$, then $x$ is put into $S$. When no more elements can be added to $S$, how many elements does $S$ have?

---

I have having trouble figuring out how to complete this problem. I am guessing this includes some form of the integer/rational root theorem, or the vieta's formula, but I'm not sure how.

Could someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you get at least one root that is not already in $S$?

Comment: Yes, $\pm1, \pm2, \pm5, -10$ (10 is already a root)

Comment: Good! Now what does the mentioned theorem tell us about the possible integer roots?

Comment: Ohhh, so is the longest going to be something like: 10 to -10 to 5 to -5 to 1 to -1, so 7 elements is the answer?

Comment: Ok, that is incorrect...Could someone please help?

Comment: You forgot $\pm2$.

Comment: Oh, for some reason I thought $\pm2$ wouldn't count since after we go from 10 to 5, 2 isn't possible anymore because 5/2 isn't an integer. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Who cares that 5/2 isn't an integer? 10/5 definitely is.